# Why isn't Main returning?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, deadlock, terminate

I've noticed this type of behavior before, and it occurred to me to ask a question this time:

I have a simple "proof of concept" program that spawns a few threads, waits for them to do some work, then exits.

But `Main` isn't returning unless I call `server.Close()` (which closes the socket and ends the server's thread's execution):

```
private void Run()
{
    var server = StartServer(); //Starts a thread in charge of listening on a socket

    _serverResetEvent.WaitOne();

    ThriftProtocolAccessManager protocolManager = CreateProtocolManager(); //Doesn't create any threads

    const int numTestThreads = 10;

    Barrier testCompletedBarrier;

    Thread[] testThreads = GenerateTestThreads(numTestThreads, protocolManager, out testCompletedBarrier); //Creates x threads, where x is numTestThreads

    testThreads
        .AsParallel()
        .ForAll(thread => thread.Start()); //Start them "at the same time" (For testing purposes 

    testCompletedBarrier.SignalAndWait(); //Barrier has participants equal to numTestThreads + 1 and each thread calls this
    //server.Close() would go here. When it is here, the program returns as expected
    Console.WriteLine("All Threads Complete"); //This is getting called
}
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program().Run();
    Console.WriteLine("Run completed"); //This is also called
}//The debugger confirms this brace is reached as well
```

According to article 10.2, "Application termination" of the ECMA C# language specs:

> If the return type of the entry point method is `void`, reaching the right brace (`}`) which terminates that method, or executing a `return` statement that has no expression, results in a termination status code of 0.

The debugger confirms that the right brace is being reached, but the standard doesn't explicitly say that leaving `Main` will exit the application, only that the termination status code is set.

It also mentions that:

> ...finalizers for all of [the application's] objects that have not yet been garbage collected are called, unless such cleanup has been suppressed (by a call to the library method `GC.SuppressFinalize`, for example).

I suspected that behind the scenes a finalizer might be the problem, since the server object implements `IDisposable`, and it's not uncommon to have a finalizer that calls `Dispose`. But the CLR limits finalizers to two seconds of execution when the program is being terminated (Just in-case something strange was happening with the timeout I tried calling `GC.SuppressFinalize` on the server object and got the same result).

I'm a bit stumped as to what the server thread could be doing to hold up termination of the application indefinitely.

Comment: what kind of "Server" is `StartServer` starting? A `TcpListener`?

Comment: I figured it was somewhat irrelevant to the question, but it's starting any of Thrift's implementations of a socket server. Internally it uses a TcpListener in combination with either a single thread, multiple threads, or the ThreadPool.

Comment: Why should this be irrelevant if this seems to block your programm from ending? I guess it's some non-background or foreground thread that get's started by this *Server* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: btw: I assume that many of this have `IDisposable` on them (like the Server, certainly the threads and I guess even the `ThriftProtocolAccessmanager`) - you should always call `Dispose` on them (that's what `using` is for ;) ) - most likely this will shutdown your server as well without you having call `Close`

Comment: To be clear, I want to know what _any thread_ could do to stop termination, I think the question would be too narrow, and have too little context if I wanted to know what this specific case is doing. Also the ThreadPool implementation has the same issue. (And a note, I realize the correct usage of IDisposable, this is a purely academic attempt to test something)

Comment: Have you seen the `IsBackground` stuff? If this is `false` your process will not terminate till the thread completes ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording used in the @Carsten König's link lead me to realize I was looking in the wrong documentation. The problem was indeed that the thread that was starting the server implementation was a foreground thread, changing it to a background thread causes the ThreadPool implementation to behave as expected.

It seems that it the ECMA standard defers the specific termination behavior (The CLI documentation didn't mention anything about it either). I'm still looking to see if I can find a general document that describes the entire termination procedure in greater detail.